# Magento 2 : Override custom option text template

Tags: magento2, template, custom-options

I tried to change the template of the text custom option in frontend.

I copied the original

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/text.phtml
```

to

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml.
```

and add to

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

my custom.phtml file is well called, but craches at the first lines :

```
<?php
    $_option = $block->getOption();
    $class = ($_option->getIsRequire()) ? ' required' : '';
?>
```

**$_option** being null after `$_option = $block->getOption()`;

Thank you for your help,

EDIT 1:

I tried for catalog_product_view.xml

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
                <referenceBlock name="text">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>
    </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

but it is not working...

Comment: why if $_option is null means that it crash?

Comment: Is get_class($block) the same with your template and default template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After hours searching on internet, it is apparently not possible to change Custom Options templates using the standard XML way...

Therefore, here is a clean solution using Plugin :

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text">
        <plugin name="my_module_change_cotexttemplate" type="My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\View\Options\TextCustOptionPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\View\Options\TextCustOptionPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\View\Options;


class TextCustOptionPlugin
{
    public function beforeSetTemplate(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text $subject,
        $template
    ) 
    {
         return ['My_Module::catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml'];
    }
}
```

if it can help !

Comment: its working for me !!! Thanks +1 up

Comment: It's working properly. Thank you...!!

Comment: But this is not working in Enterprise edition Magento2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to override template, it's a bit different from yours

```
<!-- cambio il template del blocco head -->
<referenceBlock name="html_head">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::html/head.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Without **referenceContainer** tag and change **name="text"** to **name="template"**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not manage to make it works. Please see my update

Comment: why do you use `<referenceBlock name="text">`?

Comment: If i understand correctly, the <action method="setTemplate">..</action> chnage the template of the block selected by <referenceBlock>. I think the problem is coming from the fact that custom options block do not have a "name" attribute but a "as" attribute...

Comment: i don't know what are you doing, my code works correctly and override magento template with custom template. "as" property is for magento1 i never see it in magento2.

Comment: Yes, your code work perfectly except for custom options templates... "as" is used in magento2 (cf vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml line70)

Comment: yes you are right "as" is used, i never used it, at the moment i used always "name". thx for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Write below at **catalog_product_view.xml** :

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">

            <block class="Emipro\Customoption\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="Emipro_Customoption::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some custom module to develop new feature onto. And it was an override block's template by plugin. It's no a good way. Plugin works on class instance. It works on each block that extended `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text`

The best way is override it by layout xml file. All suggestion above were wrong because try to use alias. Block and referenceBlock require name.

Open the xml when Text option field starts on Magento. It's *vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Ok! Let's do required override in custom module *app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.text">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

It works for me. And you can override it again if it needs. Plugin example above doesn't allow you for it.