# custom option, custom fields

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom-options

I try to create a "customizable options" with two extra fields, but I have the problem that when typing in one also write that same value in the other and in the "sku" field and I can not understand why this happens and how to correct it.

Here's what I have in code:

**/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference 
        for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option" 
        type="Reiz\Rotuisfuntcs\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option"/>
    <preference 
        for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" 
        type="Reiz\Rotuisfuntcs\Ui\DataProvider\Catalog\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" />
</config>
```

**/etc/product_options.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_options.xsd">
    <option name="rotimpresion" label="Rotuislas - simple function" renderer="Reiz\Rotuislas\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Type\RotImpresion">
        <inputType name="field_options" label="fields" />    
    </option>
</config>
```

**/Ui/DataProvider/Catalog/Product/Form/Modifier**

```
<?php

namespace Reiz\Rotuisfuntcs\Ui\DataProvider\Catalog\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductOptions\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Options\Price as ProductOptionsPrice;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ActionDelete;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;

/**
 * Data provider for "Customizable Options" panel
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CustomOptions extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions
{
    /**#@+
     * Custom options
     */

    // field simples
    const FIELD_TYPE_WEIGHT_ONE = 'one';
    const FIELD_TYPE_WEIGHT_TWO = 'two';
    const FIELD_TYPE_IMG_URL = 'papels';

    protected function getStaticTypeContainerConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                        'breakLine' => false,
                        'showLabel' => false,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-group-columns admin__control-group-equal',
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME => $this->getPriceFieldConfig(10),
                static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME => $this->getPriceTypeFieldConfig(20),
                static::FIELD_SKU_NAME => $this->getSkuFieldConfig(30),
                static::FIELD_TYPE_WEIGHT_ONE => $this->getWeight_height_FieldConfig(30),
                static::FIELD_TYPE_WEIGHT_TWO => $this->getWeight_width_FieldConfig(30),
                static::FIELD_MAX_CHARACTERS_NAME => $this->getMaxCharactersFieldConfig(40),
                static::FIELD_FILE_EXTENSION_NAME => $this->getFileExtensionFieldConfig(50),
                static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_X_NAME => $this->getImageSizeXFieldConfig(60),
                static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_Y_NAME => $this->getImageSizeYFieldConfig(70)
            ]
        ];
    }


    protected function getTypeFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Option Type'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/custom-options-type',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                        'selectType' => 'optgroup',
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_TYPE_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'options' => $this->getProductOptionTypes(),
                        'disableLabel' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'selectedPlaceholders' => [
                            'defaultPlaceholder' => __('-- Please select --'),
                        ],
                        'validation' => [
                            'required-entry' => true
                        ],
                        'groupsConfig' => [
                            'text' => [
                                'values' => ['field', 'area'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_MAX_CHARACTERS_NAME
                                ]
                            ],
                            'file' => [
                                'values' => ['file'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_FILE_EXTENSION_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_X_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_Y_NAME
                                ]
                            ],
                            'select' => [
                                'values' => ['drop_down', 'radio', 'checkbox', 'multiple'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::GRID_TYPE_SELECT_NAME
                                ]
                            ],
                            'data' => [
                                'values' => ['date', 'date_time', 'time'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME
                                ]
                            ],
                            'rotimpresion' => [
                                'values' => ['field_options'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_TYPE_WEIGHT_ONE,
                                    static::FIELD_TYPE_WEIGHT_TWO,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_MAX_CHARACTERS_NAME
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function getWeight_height_FieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Field 1: '),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    protected function getWeight_width_FieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Field 2: '),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    protected function getUrl_FieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
       return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Url image: '),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Here I leave links in which I have been referencing:

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/custom-input-types-custom-options

[Magento 2 : Override custom option text template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184810/magento-2-override-custom-option-text-template)

Comment: Resolved Changed value in dataScope,

 'dataScope' => static::FIELD_SKU_NAME 

for 

'dataScope' => static::YOUR_CONSTANT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved as follow:**

Changed value in dataScope

> 'dataScope' => static::FIELD_SKU_NAME for 'dataScope' =>
>   static::YOUR_CONSTANT

```
protected function getWeight_width_FieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Field 2: '),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: How to display it front end