# How to get the custom option in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have created custom field in custom option by using

[custom option, custom fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192833/custom-option-custom-fields)

I want to get my custom option from $block->getOption();

But my custom field not added in the list ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $o) {
    if ($o->getTitle() != 'Color') { // or another title of option
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        print_r($value->getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have add is_default field in custom option .... I want to default select the radio button which option values has is_default= 1..How to do this...

Comment: is_default  is custom options title or value

Comment: title .........

Comment: try this  if ($o->getTitle() == 'is_default') { 
        //your conditions continue;
    }